# фильтрация объекта angular

Tags: angularjs

```js
var orderApp = angular.module('orderApp', []);

orderApp.controller('orderCtrl', function ($scope) {
 $scope.inputParams = {
  "shopList": {
   "22": {
    "name": 'Пятерочка',
    "isTrue": true
   },
   "222": {
    "name": 'АШАН',
    "isTrue": false
   },
   "333": {
    "name": 'тест',
    "isTrue": true
   }
  }
 };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="orderApp" ng-controller="orderCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(item, key) in inputParams.shopList | filter:{isTrue:true}" >
      {{key.name}}
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

как отфильтровать объект по параметру isTrue?

Вообще задача заключается в том что из одного массива у меня будет делаться 2 списка, в первом будет Товар в наличии а во втором нет

Comment: никак: фильтр `filter` работает **только** с массивами. Если хочешь его тут использовать сделай из своего объекта _shopList_ - массив. Либо фильтруй в коде яваскрипт и в разметке используй уже подготовленный массив

Comment: Создайте два массива и перебирайте их в разных местах при выводе.

Comment: @mix, какие два массива и зачем их перебирать?

Comment: @Grundy массив с данными с параметром `isTrue: true` и второй массив с данными с параметром `isTrue: false`. Перебирать в html - выводить пользователю.

Comment: @mix, тогда и третий массив нужен - без фильтрации

Comment: @Grundy Зачем? Автор хочет два списка сделать.

Comment: @mix, например, чтобы показать _все товары_

Comment: @Grundy есть такая потребность в вопросе автора?

Comment: @mix, никто не говорит, что ее нет

Comment: @Grundy то, что она есть, тоже никто не говорит

Comment: нужно только 2 списка, победил @Grundy ))))